# Html - PHP - Robots

Tags: php, opencart, robots.txt, google-index

I am just looking for a bit of advice / feedback, I was thinking about setting up and opencart behind an HTML site (shop) that gets ranked well in Google.

The index.html site appears instead of the index.php page by default on the web server (I have tested it).

I was hoping I could construct the site in maintenance mode on the domain, then just delete the html site leaving the (live) opencart site once finished (about 2 weeks).

Just worried in case this may effect ranking.

In the robot.txt file put:

```
User-agent: *
User-agent: Googlebot

Disallow: /index.php
```

I would also put in the index.php page (opencart) header:

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, noarchive">
```

I don't want Google to cache the "website under maintenance" opencart index.php page. It could take a month or so to refresh it.

Obviously I would remove/change the Disallow robot.txt and meta tag etc commands once live and html site files deleted.

I would like to know if any one has tried it or if it will work? Effect google ranking etc?

Is it just a Bad idea? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: you can always do internal rewrites to redirect traffic from .html to .php. or simply tell your server to treat .html files as php scripts and slip your php code into the index.html. there's LOTS of options for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, i am really looking to delete the html site and use the opencart site once it is all finished.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using LAMP for your website (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP)

1) Apache has option to set default page, set it to index.php instead of index.html

2) You may either use re-write rule in `.htaccess` file (read more [here](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/how-to-edit-htaccess/). If your hosting provider doesn't give permission to .htaccess, there's a workaround!
In `index.php` you may include this snippet at the top:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php'){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: /");
    die();
}
?>
```

So even if user opens up `http://www.domain.com/index.php`,
he'll get redirected to `http://www.domain.com/`

(Eg: My site http://theypi.net/index.php goes to http://theypi.net/)

I've also set similar redirect for http://www.theypi.net to redirect to http://theypi.net
Choosing between one of the two options (with or without www) helps improve ranking as well)

To your question

> I would like to know if any one has tried it or if it will work? Effect google ranking etc?

1. Shorter URL: This is part of URL hygiene which is meant for SEO improvement
2. If homepage opens just through domain name (without index.php) then your CTR (Click Through Rate) impact in search results is higher.

I would suggest not to use robot blocking mechanism unless above steps aren't feasible for you.

Hope it helps, Thanks!

**Edit**:
And if you don't even have permission to set homepage as index.php. You may do one of following:
 1. create `index.html` and put php code. If WebServer understands php, put redirect logic as above.
 2. else, put JavaScript redirect (not a recommended way)
`<script language=”JavaScript”> self.location=”index.php”; </script>`